# Converting a 3 digit date that is just text to a full date using odbc export to file

Tags: sql, odbc

I need to convert a date but its not a date its more like text the customer entered into a field.

The client is using Access db and the recall date is the name of his field he types in 215 meaning feburary 2015 with my current setup it works fine but when the first number is a double digit this method doesnt work. Like 1115 becomes 1/1/2015

Here is my code

> `left("recall date",1)+'/01/20'+ right("recall date",2) as Recalldate`

I tried to do something really complex for me and turned out failing over and over again

```
iif(len("recall date" =4), Csng(left("recall date",2))+'/01/20'+ csng(right("recall date",2)) , csng(left("recall date",1))+'/01/20'+ csng(right("recall date",2)))
```

the current setup will odbc export this information to a text file let me know if you guys need more information thanks

Answer (score 0):

My idea is to add leading zero to values with only 3 digits, split it into two parts and add '20' as year prefix:

```
SELECT DateValue(Mid(Format(cint('215'), '0000'), 1, 2) & '/20' & Mid(Format(cint('215'), '0000'), 3, 2))
-- 2015-02-01 00:00:00

SELECT DateValue(Mid(Format(cint('1115'), '0000'), 1, 2) & '/20' & Mid(Format(cint('1115'), '0000'), 3, 2))
-- 2015-11-01 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    iif ( len([recall date]) = 3, 
   left("recall date",1)+'/01/20'+ right("recall date",2), 
   left("recall date",2)+'/01/20'+ right("recall date",2)) 
as Recalldate
```